# If a request variable is present then unique validation on one table if not unique validation on other table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a senario, I have One field and I want to validate it on some condition like,
If request has check field then apply unique validation on another table and if not present apply the same unique validation rule on the another table.

```
if ($request->input('check')) {
    $request->validate([
        'field' => [
            Rule::unique('one_table', 'one_column')
        ],
    ]);
} else {
    $request->validate([
        'field' => [
            Rule::unique('another_table', 'another_column')
        ],
    ]);
}
```

check and field are supposed request variables.

I don't know how to combine these condition into one condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you can use short condition :

```php
$request->validate([
    'field' => [
        ($request->input('check')?  Rule::unique('one_table', 'one_column'):Rule::unique('another_table', 'another_column'))
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Thank You. it worked. 
there should be a rule like uniqueIf() may be.

Comment: You are welcome) For rules you can see documentation laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation